# Google Calendar and Looker integrations

Tags: api, looker

Is it possible to sync between Google calendar and Looker?

I want to pull out events through their API, and store them in my calendar table.

I searched and didn't find a solution that does not require payment to an external company.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In order to view your Google Calendar data in Looker, you'll need to first push that information into a table in your database.

For example, you could create and schedule a Python script that grabs the data from the Google Calendar API and appends it to a calendar table in your database.

If you provide some more details on your database and what programming language you feel comfortable working in, I can go into some more detail